# How to get Next Due Date

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have a two table. One Customer Table and other one is Scheduled table that holds Scheduled Transactions and include the next scheduled payment date.  I need to run the report daily  - I need to work out the next due date - based on today's date.

Below is the script I wrote

```
select a.ApplicationId
, d.Reference as ' Payment Reference'
,a.PaymentMethod
,sch.Date as 'Next Payment due Date' 
from [dbo].[Application]  as a
left join  [Direct Debit] as d on d.ApplicationId =a.ApplicationId
left join [Schedule] as sch on sch.ApplicationId=a.ApplicationId
where PaymentMethod ='Direct Debit' and  sch.Scheduletype='InstalmentSchedule'  and sch.applicationID =6923
GROUP BY a.ApplicationId, d.Reference,a.PaymentMethod,sch.Date
```

[image: Due Date]

Comment: And what might your logic be for the next due date?  Such information -- along with sample data and desired results -- would be helpful.

Comment: LInks to images of data *really* don't help us help you. Data is text and thus should be provided as `text`; preferably DDL and DML statements but otherwise well formatted tabular `text`.

Comment: below is the output for above code. This give me full Schedule payment. IN the example the next due date is line number 2 which "2020-05-13 00:00:00"

Comment: You join three of the two tables you have in order to get results you've shown from data you haven't shared. It _might_ be that you want a calculated value for `Next Payment due Date`, but currently just select a column (`sch.Date`). No DDL or sample data and no meaningful explanation. Is that a vague enough description of why we are having trouble helping you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a subselect to your schedule to only get the next date in the future

```
SELECT
    a.ApplicationId
   ,d.Reference AS 'Payment Reference'
   ,a.PaymentMethod
   ,sch.Date AS 'Next Payment due Date'
FROM [dbo].[Application] AS a
LEFT JOIN [Direct Debit] AS d
    ON d.ApplicationId = a.ApplicationId
LEFT JOIN (SELECT
        ApplicationId
       ,Scheduletype
       ,MIN([Date]) [Date]
    FROM [Schedule]
    WHERE [Date] > GETDATE()
    GROUP BY ApplicationId
            ,Scheduletype) AS sch
    ON sch.ApplicationId = a.ApplicationId
WHERE PaymentMethod = 'Direct Debit'
AND sch.Scheduletype = 'InstalmentSchedule'
AND sch.applicationID = 6923
GROUP BY a.ApplicationId
        ,d.Reference
        ,a.PaymentMethod
        ,sch.Date
```

The subselect being:

```
SELECT
    ApplicationId
   ,Scheduletype
   ,MIN([Date]) [Date]
FROM [Schedule]
WHERE [Date] > GETDATE() /* date must be in the future */
GROUP BY ApplicationId
        ,Scheduletype
```